# php5 curl installation error

Tags: 14.04, php, curl

When I was trying to install php5 using curl I got the error as shown in the image.

[image]

Does anyone have a solution to this.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `apt-cache policy php-5.6`? It appears you chose a really weird package source that its author marked as “private”. Hence the “Forbidden” HTTP status that you can see in the output of Apt. Based on what instructions did you choose the repository?